# Validating sets of radio buttons a second time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm making a form asking users about a tournament. I need to limit each placement to only having one team and vise versa. I have the latter figured out already. But I'm having trouble thinking of a way to further validate the radio buttons. The set is in a 4x4 grid and each column and row should only have one value. I can get the teams validation to work by naming the buttons the same but I can't find a way to validate the placement. I had a way to validate checkboxes but I need to use radio buttons so I can have what order users place each checked box so I can read what teams are placed in 1st and 2nd in each group.

The way the teams, placement, and button are laid out is within a table.

```
<form>
<table class="groupSeating" cellspacing="2">
<caption>Group Seating</caption>

  <colgroup>
    <col class="groups" />
    <col class="teams" />
    <col class="seating" span="4" />
  </colgroup>

  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2" colspan="2"></th>
    <th colspan="4">Seating</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1st</td>
    <td>2nd</td>
    <td>3rd</td>
    <td>4th</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4">Group A</td>
    <td>ROX Tigers</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="roxSeed" id="ROX1" value="ROX" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="roxSeed" id="ROX2" value="ROX" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="roxSeed" id="ROX3" value="ROX" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="roxSeed" id="ROX4" value="ROX" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>G2 Esports</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="g2Seed" id="G21" value="G2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="g2Seed" id="G22" value="G2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="g2Seed" id="G23" value="G2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="g2Seed" id="G24" value="G2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Counter Logic Gaming</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="clgSeed" id="CLG1" value="CLG" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="clgSeed" id="CLG2" value="CLG" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="clgSeed" id="CLG3" value="CLG" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="clgSeed" id="CLG4" value="CLG" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Albux Nox Luna</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="anxSeed" id="ANX1" value="ANX" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="anxSeed" id="ANX2" value="ANX" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="anxSeed" id="ANX3" value="ANX" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="anxSeed" id="ANX4" value="ANX" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

There is probably a cleaner way for my code but I'm not worried about that, it's for a school project. I tried taking bits from another js that was for checkboxes but I can't think of what to change.

```
var limit = 2;

$('input.singleCheckbox').on('change', function(evt) {
  if ($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
    this.checked = false;
  }
});
```

Comment: First of all, IDs on the page should be unique

Comment: `$('.groupSeating :checked').length == 4` should do it.

Comment: @Malk shouldn't I do `$('.groupSeating :checked').length == 1` because I only want one not 4?

Comment: @ClayHayes You don't need JS. You just need to swap input names.

Comment: @fremail I need the input names to stay the same so the team is limited to one placement. I need to limit the placements to one per team with JS.

Comment: @ClayHayes, I don't know. But if you want to make sure all 4 groups have something checked you would look for 4 checked inputs. If you want only 1 group to have something checked you would check for 1 checked input...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

https://jsfiddle.net/277uu501/2/

```
var reject = false;

$('input[type="radio"]')
  .mouseup(function(){
    var selectedValues = [];
    $('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(){
      selectedValues.push($(this).parent().index());
    });

    var selectedValue = $(this).parent().index();
    reject = selectedValues.indexOf(selectedValue) != -1;
  })

  .change(function(){
    if(reject) this.checked = false;
  });
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. It works flawlessly in JSFiddle but when I try using it in my HTML it stops working.

Comment: I removed: <td rowspan="4">Group A</td> from your html

Comment: Also, like the comments have said already, you should only use an ID once in your html. You should change those to classes.

Comment: They needed to be IDs and I've changed them so they're all unique.

Comment: I have the `<td rowspan="4">Group A</td>` in there because I have four groups. I only listed one here because it's easier to work with a 4x4 rather than a 4x16 grid.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I got the idea.
Try this JS code:

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
  var initiator = $(this);
  var value = initiator.val();
  var counter = 0;
  $('input:checked').each(function(i, elem) {
    if (elem.value === value) {
      counter++;
    }
  });
  if (counter > 1) {
    initiator.prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

It won't allow to check more than one radio button on the row/column